# -webkit-appearance: none; doesn't work on Safari macOS

Tags: html, css, reactjs, macos, safari

I'm styling a form select button which I already set these:

```
.input-form select {
-moz-appearance: none;
-webkit-appearance: none;
appearance: none;
...
}
```

HTML:

```
<form className="input-form" onSubmit={e => handleSubmit(e)}>
    <div className="select-domain">
        <label name="Select Domain">Select Domain</label>
        <select name="Select Domain" onChange={e => handleDomainChange(e)}>
            <option value="example.com">example.com</option>
            <option value="custom">Custom domain</option>
        </select>   
    </div>            
    <button type="submit">Start</button>
</form>
```

It works everywhere, even on Safari mobile, but apparently Safari macOS chooses to ignore. What could be the cause?

I'm using macOS version 11.2.3 (20D91)
Safari Version 14.0.3 (16610.4.3.1.7)

and it's a React app btw

Comment: Your Safari version? Also show your related HTML codes please.

Comment: @Raptor sorry, just added

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found it, but not so sure why it worked: Remove `appearance: none`. Now `-webkit-appearance: none` is respected.

Answer (score 0):

According to [MDN doc](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/appearance), Safari v3 - 15.3 uses `-webkit-apperance`, while Safari v15.4+ uses `appearance` CSS property.

Either way, the `select` element should have no "appearance", i.e. no dropdown box (but not hidden). A black border appears in Safari v15.5 (that's the version I got now). If you want the black border to be gone, add `border: none`.

```
.input-form select {
  -moz-appearance: none;
  -webkit-appearance: none;
  appearance: none;
  border: none;
}
```

Here is the [JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/monb3j0c/).

Comment: Actually Safari strikes out the appearance as not supported property
See screenshot: https://pasteboard.co/6WobTRNqKZU3.png

Comment: In your version (14.0.3), it uses `-webkit-appearance`, that's why `appearance` is stroke out. Why do you have 2 `appearance: none`?

Comment: 2 `appearance: none`: I just inspect it and try adding it directly from the browser to see if It works. 
And yes, `-webkit-appearance` was set none along with `appearance`  and `-moz-appearance` all together, but Safari ignored it

Comment: so how does the JSFiddle perform in your browser? Does it work as expected?

Comment: JSFiddle works properly tho. Now I have to figure out what's wrong with my CSS file

Comment: Try to clear cache & hard reload

Comment: I tried everything and this worked: removed `appearance: none` and suddenly `-webkit-appearance` is now being respected.

Comment: Glad your issue is solved.